# Add Legend In ggplot2 after adding geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have created a graph that overlays a normally distributed density plot on top of a previous density plot using the dnorm() function. However, I am having a difficult time adding a legend. Below is the code to create the plot with one of my attempts at adding a legend.

```
library(tidyverse)

my.data = rnorm(1000, 3, 10)

ggplot(enframe(my.data), aes(value)) +
      geom_density(fill = "mediumseagreen", alpha = 0.1) +
      geom_area(stat = "function", fun = function(x) dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 5), fill = "red", alpha = .5)+ 
      theme(legend.position="right")+
      scale_color_manual("Line.Color", values=c(red="red",green="green"),
                          labels=paste0("Plot",1:2))
```

To summarize I am trying to add a legend to this plot that has labels "Plot1" and "Plot2"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be better answers. This is what I have achieved with several attemps:

```
library(tidyverse)

my.data = rnorm(1000, 3, 10)

  ggplot(enframe(my.data), aes(value)) +
    geom_density(aes(color = "Plot1", fill = "Plot1"), alpha = 0.1) +
    geom_area(aes(color = "Plot2", fill = "Plot2"), stat = "function", 
              fun = function(x) dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 5), alpha = .5)+ 
    theme(legend.position="right") + 
    scale_color_manual(" ", values=c(Plot1="green", Plot2="red")) +  
    scale_fill_manual(" ", values=c(Plot1 ="green", Plot2="red"))
```

[image]

Comment: anychance you would know how to move the legend to lets say the bottom? Using theme(legend.position = "bottom") does not seem to work for this example

Comment: `theme(legend.position="bottom")` works well on my machine. If you show your code, I will try to work out why.